# How to add context path in the swagger ui / open api in try it out

Tags: swagger, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using springdoc-openapi-ui for documenting my REST end point.

Below is the pom dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is my swagger url

http://localhost:40001/test/swagger-ui/index.html

The swagger UI opens perfectly fine. When I go one of the controllers and click "try it out" and execute the rest endpoint I get an 404 error.

When I check the request url it is

http://localhost:40001/my-service/v1/topic/123

I expect the request url to be http://localhost:40001/test/my-service/v1/topic/123 instead of the above one.

The "try it out" is missing the context path "test"

I have specified the below property in my application.properties

server.servlet.context-path=/test

The "try it out" is not adding the context path "test" to its request url.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I had the below annotation in my configuration file

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@Server(url = "/", description = "Default Server URL")})
```

Which cause causing the context path to be defaulted to /. Removing the above annotation resolved the issue